# Why can't I combine CHECK constraint with ON UPDATE CASCADE?

Tags: mariadb, innodb, foreign-key, check-constraints

Given table A:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
 `id` int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

when I try to create this second table B:

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
 `id` int NOT NULL,
 `val1` int,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `a_nonsense_foreign_key` FOREIGN KEY (`val1`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `a_nonsense_check` CHECK (`val1` > 10)
);
```

I get the following error message:

```
SQL Error [1901] [HY000]: (conn=6) Function or expression 'val1' cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `a_nonsense_check`
```

If i change the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` I get no errors.

Another observation is that `ON DELETE CASCADE` doesn't generate errors.

Why is it that the `CHECK` constraint cannot be combined with the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` statement?
Can I find this behaviour in the documentation somewhere?

I am using MariaDB and I believe the standard engine is InnoDB.

**And a short disclaimer:** I am new to databases, and the root of this problem might be an XY-problem. I am, however, curious to why this limitation exists or if I am doing something wrong :)

Comment: What version are you using? 10.6 seems to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/Nxq_N1Zl

Comment: Fwiw, all versions available at db<>fiddle seems to work

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bvWgZ21c) exercising constraints.

Comment: I am running MariaDB 11.2.2 on windows. So the version differs.
Otherwise, could there be a setting with the database itself? Here is the reported create statement:

    CREATE DATABASE `testdatabase` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci */

Comment: I did some more testing regarding versions on Windows. The fiddle statement works in 10.9.4 but not in 10.9.5.

Another observation is that fiddle breaks if you try to update the referred row in table A. Since I only get the "run failed" message from fiddle, I don't get a link to share..

Comment: "run failed" could be it crashing the server. The short term support release of 10.9 and 10.10 is [out of maintaince](https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy). You can update the question with the SQL that caused the "run failed".